# MySQL: Query a subset of rows

Tags: mysql, subset

Give the table below:

TABLE : USER_ASSETS

```
USER_ID | ASSET_ID
-------------------
1       |  1
-------------------
1       |  2
-------------------
1       |  3
-------------------
2       |  2
-------------------
2       |  3
-------------------
```

If I search for the `USER_ID` with `ASSET_ID` equals to 1 and 2, it should return `USER_ID` 1 as `USER_ID` 1 has `ASSET_ID`'s 1 and 2.

If I pass `ASSET_ID` = 1 and 2 and 4, it should return 0 rows as there are no `USER_ID`'s that have `ASSET_ID` 1, 2 and 4.

If I pass `ASSET_ID` 2 and 3 it should return `USER_ID` 1 and 2 as both of these `USER_ID`'s has `ASSET_ID` 2 and 3.

I'm stuck right now as i couldn't find the correct query for my desired result.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM USER_ASSETS WHERE ASSET_ID IN (1, 2);
```

But the result is wrong as it returns both USER_ID 1 and 2.

I have also tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM USER_ASSETS WHERE ASSET_ID = 1 AND ASSET_ID = 2
```

But this always return to 0 rows as the WHERE clause is executed to a single row at a time.

Comment: thanks for the edit @Dijkgraaf,   I am thinking of using a join of the same table for every ASSET_ID value, but is it the correct approach?

Comment: no it isn't (well, it's a solution, but imo an unecessarily complicated one). see answer below.

Comment: See Misandrist's answer where he does exactly that, but it gets a bit unwieldy very fast. Pala_'s answer might also work. Try them out

Comment: I have tried it and it is working, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
select user_id
  from user_assets
  where asset_id = 1 or asset_id = 2 ...
  group by user_id
  having count(distinct asset_id) = (number of assets you are looking for)
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e7af/1) showing your required output.

the distinct isn't necessary if `(user_id, asset_id)` is a unique key

Comment: Thank you, this is returning exactly the rows that  i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE ASSET_ID IN (1, 2)` is the same as `WHERE ASSET_ID = 1 OR ASSET_ID = 2`, and both `USER_ID` 1 and `USER_ID` 2 have records with `ASSET_ID` = 2, so this `WHERE` clause will include both those rows.

`WHERE ASSET_ID = 1 AND ASSET_ID = 2` will fail because there's no single row that has both 1 and 2 for `ASSET_ID`.

I think what you're asking is how to retrieve a `USER_ID` that has all of a set of `ASSET_ID`s. In that case you'll need to build a more complex query:

```
SELECT A1.USER_ID 
FROM USER_ASSETS AS A1 
INNER JOIN USER_ASSETS AS A2
ON A1.USER_ID = A2.USER_ID
WHERE A1.ASSET_ID = 1 AND A2.ASSET_ID = 2
```

This will return all `USER_ID` values that have both `ASSET_ID` 1 and `ASSET_ID` 2. You can add as many `INNER JOIN` clauses and additional `An.ASSET_ID` conditions to the `WHERE` clause as you need.

Comment: Yes exactly, can you please tell me the correct approach?  Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this JOIN is also what i thought about , but the ASSET_ID rows might be more than 10 and this means a join for the table 10x which will impact performance